# Android Lock Pattern Errors

Tags: android

I'm trying to use [Android Lock Pattern](https://code.google.com/p/android-lockpattern/wiki/QuickUse)

But when I import the library into Eclipse, it got these errors :

> IContentView cannot be resolved to a type 
>       R cannot be resolved to a variable
>       Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token )

Code get errors : ***implements IContentView***

```
public class LockPatternActivity extends Activity implements IContentView {

  private static final String CLASSNAME = LockPatternActivity.class.getName();

/**
 * Use this action to create new pattern. You can provide an
 * {@link IEncrypter} with
 * {@link Security#setEncrypterClass(android.content.Context, Class)} to
 * improve security.
 * <p/>
 * If the user created a pattern, {@link Activity#RESULT_OK} returns with
 * the pattern ({@link #EXTRA_PATTERN}). Otherwise
 * {@link Activity#RESULT_CANCELED} returns.
 * 
 * @see #EXTRA_PENDING_INTENT_OK
 * @see #EXTRA_PENDING_INTENT_CANCELLED
 * @since v2.4 beta
```

Anyone used to facing this problem? How to solve that?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Clean the project and build it again.

Comment: make sure you are importing the library in a correct way.http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: i followed the instruction by the site :By Eclipse: Right click on your project, select Properties, select Android tab, then add this library to Library box.

Comment: Do you organize the imports ,Missing imports in java files. Press in Eclipse this shortcut Ctrl+Shift+O to organize imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following..

- Right Click library project >> Build Path >> Configure Build Path >> Android >> Select latest android api >> Apply >> OK
- Clean the library project after importing.  Project >> clean >> select your library project of lock pattern

Comment: try removing "implements IContentView"  because I dont have that part in my code of same library project. I am not aware how it is but its not there.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I caught the library which the link of demo app direct us. The library avaliable at site have problems. But the library found in link demo app link it's working. Using this library it's possible implement the guidelines site and compile without problems. See the options menu

> Export source code

at the demo app to get the library.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [this](https://github.com/asghonim/simple_android_lock_pattern) library.